# Where to find default/ test page for Apache2

Tags: apache2, webserver, html

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 13.10 and has an Apache2 website, and whenever I go to the VPS's IP `http://5.231.37.8` ,I get the default/test page for Apache instead of [my website](http://wolfy1339.tk) located in `/var/www`.

It's an html + css website.

Edit: My [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/413850/235368) below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

Add a new virtual host for the ip address in the file located at `\etc\apache2\sites-available\000-default.conf` 
as `<VirtualHost *:80>` 
and change `ServerName` to the IP.

In 
`\etc\apache2\sites-available\default-ssl.conf` 
(if you have ssl enabled) as

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

and change `ServerName` to the IP.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the html home page file is in `/var/www`, **and is called `index.html`** - `index.html` is the first/default webpage you should get on typing the sites domain name/IP address. All other files can be linked to & from the `index.html` root/home file.

Comment: My website is in `/var/www` but it won't load if i directly go to my VPS's ip address. Only loads if i go to http://mywebsite.com

Comment: Even `http://???.???.?.??/index.html`? Could be the wrong IP address...

Comment: no, it wasn't incorrect

Answer (score 0):

The default apache2 start page is found under /var/www and named index.html. It will run by default whenevr you try to access your webserver(apache2) either by calling `http://localhost/` or `http://your-ip`

For your site to run smoothly just put your html and css files inside a directory in `/var/www` name it mysite for example. Then you can run your default(index.html) file of your site just by locating to `/var/www/mysite`

Comment: That's where my website is as stated in my question.